# Different Twitter share buttons for randomly generated content

Tags: javascript, html, button, twitter

I need to create a page with randomly generated content. Each content will have a different Twitter share button for each, using a JavaScript file. I used the Twitter generated button for sharing, but it does not work in my JavaScript file.

Code:

```
if (randomNumber === 0){
     shareContent.innerHTML ='
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="THIS IS THE FIRST TEXT TO SHARE" data-url="http://ecosdevrindavana.com/quotes/index.html" data-related="AvatarDorado" data-lang="es" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a> ${async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"}';
    
}else if(randomNumber == 1){
     shareContent.innerHTML ='
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="THIS IS THE SECOND TEXT TO SHARE" data-url="http://ecosdevrindavana.com/quotes/index.html" data-related="AvatarDorado" data-lang="es" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a> ${async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"}';
}
```

The original "share" button:

```
<a href="twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="TEXT TO SHARE" data-url="ecosdevrindavana.com/quotes/index.html" data-related="AvatarDorado" data-lang="es" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a> <script async src="platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This is the original share button:

<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="TEXT TO SHARE" data-url="http://ecosdevrindavana.com/quotes/index.html" data-related="AvatarDorado" data-lang="es" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving? In your web browser, go to settings -> Tools -> Developer Tools (or similar) and look at the Console tab. what is there? I also noticed that your original post had back-ticks (`) where quotes (") should be in the Javascript code. Was that something you intended?

Comment: @MichaelHawkins
I don't have any message there, any error, but the button does not have the Twiter image expected in the frontpage, and does not charge the "TEXT TO SHARE" just the link to Twitter. As you see, the button code is HTML, but at the end it has a script: `<script async src="platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`. I don't know how to combine both codes (html + javascript) inside a js file.
I just tried to change the script `<script>` with `${}`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution thanks to @SalomonHenao:

````
 var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("src", "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        let buttonHtml = `
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="` + quotes[randomNumber] + `" data-url="http://ecosdevrindavana.com/quotes/index.html" data-related="AvatarDorado" data-lang="es" data-show-count="false">Tweet<//a>`;

        document.getElementById('completo').innerHTML = buttonHtml;
    ```
````